# Splash screen size of Nexus 7 (Android)

Tags: android, nexus-7

What should be the splash screen size for Nexus 7, and how do i differentiate
various screens and set splash screen of different size for each of them?

Please suggest.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks... i will check the link..